# Is it possible to use Object.defineProperty in Auth0 Rules?

Tags: javascript, auth0

I'm trying to create the following rule on Auth0:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  // TODO: implement your rule
  var app = 'authorization';
  var obj = {};
  Object.defineProperty(obj, app, { roles: 'admin, customer'});
  user.obj = obj;
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

When I try the rule the user.obj property is equals {}

```
{
  ...
  "obj": {},
  "user_id": "auth0|0123456789",
  ...
}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. *value* is equal to the given value.

```
const app = 'authorization';
const obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, app, { 
    value: { roles: 'admin, customer' },
    writable: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even with the change, it still is not working ... I think it is something related with Auth0...